# About the notation $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f(x),p)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, field-theory

Let $f(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ be a polynomial and $p$ be a prime. What does the notation $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f(x),p)$ mean? Is it $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f(x))$ ?

Answer (score 5):

$(f(x),p)$ is the ideal generated by $f(x)$ and $p$, that is the smallest subset of $\mathbb Z[x]$ that contains $f(x)$ and $p$ and is closed under addition and multiplication with elements of $\mathbb Z[x]$. Hence the elements of $(f(x),p)$ can be written as $f(x)g(x)+ph(x)$ with $g,h\in\mathbb Z[x]$.

Now $\mathbb Z[x]/(f(x),p)$ is the ring of polynomials modulo that ideal. It can be *viewed* as (is canonically isomorphic to) $(\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z)[x]$ modulo $(\bar f(x)$ where $\bar f$ is the reduction of $f$ modulo $p$ (coefficientwise).